# One to Many relation in datomic

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datomic, datalog, datascript

Let's say I have a datomic data that looks like this -

```
Author (id: 5) {
 name: "Mercy",
 blogs: [1, 2]
}

Blog (id: 1) {
 title: "Hello blog"
}

Blog (id: 2) {
 title: "Hello blog second"
}
```

I want to find a author by name and all the title of their blogs and count of blogs. So far, I have

```
[:find ?blogs ?c
 :where
 [?e :name "Mercy"]
 [?e :blogs ?blogs]
 [(count ?blogs) ?c]
]
```

I was only able to get the total count of blogs. How can I get the title of the blogs using just datalog queries? I also cannot have belongs_to relationship on the blog entity.

**Update**

'author/blogs' has schema that looks like:

```
{
 :db/ident :blog
 :db/valueType :db.type/ref
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `:title` from the entities after [pulling](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2017/4/21/separation-of-concerns-in-datomic-query-datalog-query-and-pull-expressions) all the attributes of the entity:

```
[:find [(pull ?blogs '[:title]) ...] ?count
 :where
 [?e :name "Mercy"]
 [?e :blogs ?blogs]
 [(count ?blogs) ?count]
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: it didn't work :( . ?blogs is just a vector of refs. i want to use the ids in that vector to fetch the blogs.

Comment: @Lordking clear. You need to pull the rest of the attributes. Let me update the answer, so you can check. :)

Comment: doing (pull ?blogs [:title]) seems to work for me (not what i want) but not [(pull ?blogs '[:title]) ...]

Comment: @Lordking great. Why isn't it what you want? You retrieve all titles right? Using the Entities API as specified by Nikita above is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It’s just

```
[:find ?e (count ?b)
 :where
 [?e :name "Mercy"]
 [?e :blogs ?b]]
```

It would work even if you remove author’s name, then you’ll get “map” of author → blog count

```
[:find ?e ?n (count ?b)
 :where
 [?e :name ?n]
 [?e :blogs ?b]]
```

Don’t forget for these queries to work efficiently `:name` should be indexed (`:db/index true` in schema).

But if the question is that simple, I’d recommend to go through entities API really, should be much more efficient:

```
(-> (d/entity db [:name "Mary"])
    (:blogs)
    (count))
```

For ref lookup to work (`(d/entity db [:name "Mary"])`), you’ll need to specify `:name` as unique attribute in schema